# aws-cli dynamodb create table with multiple secondary index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am trying to create a dynamodb table with 2 local secondary indexes.  I did the following and only the latter index(index-2) applied.  What's the correct way of doing this?

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
 --table-name test_table_name \
 --attribute-definitions \
     AttributeName=type,AttributeType=S \
     ...
 --key-schema \
     AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH \
     AttributeName=id,KeyType=RANGE \
 --provisioned-throughput \
     ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
 --local-secondary-indexes \
     'IndexName=index-1,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=sk1,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=INCLUDE,NonKeyAttributes=[A,B,C,D]}' \
 --local-secondary-indexes \
     'IndexName=index-2,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=sk2,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=INCLUDE,NonKeyAttributes=[B,D,F,H]}' \
 --region us-east-1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to specify single `--local-secondary-indexes` such as

**before**

```
 --local-secondary-indexes \
     'IndexName=index-1,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=sk1,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=INCLUDE,NonKeyAttributes=[A,B,C,D]}' \
 --local-secondary-indexes \
     'IndexName=index-2,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=sk2,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=INCLUDE,NonKeyAttributes=[B,D,F,H]}' \
```

**After**

```
 --local-secondary-indexes \
     'IndexName=index-1,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=sk1,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=INCLUDE,NonKeyAttributes=[A,B,C,D]}' \
     'IndexName=index-2,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=sk2,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=INCLUDE,NonKeyAttributes=[B,D,F,H]}' \
```

**Final**

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
 --table-name test_table_name \
 --attribute-definitions \
     AttributeName=type,AttributeType=S \
     ...
 --key-schema \
     AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH \
     AttributeName=id,KeyType=RANGE \
 --provisioned-throughput \
     ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
 --local-secondary-indexes \
     'IndexName=index-1,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=sk1,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=INCLUDE,NonKeyAttributes=[A,B,C,D]}' \
     'IndexName=index-2,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=type,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=sk2,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=INCLUDE,NonKeyAttributes=[B,D,F,H]}' \
 --region us-east-1
```