# How to create multiple GSI when creating a table from the CLI - DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to create a table from the CLI that has a few GSIs. However, It is returning an error:

> Parameter validation failed: Missing required parameter in
>   GlobalSecondaryIndexes[5]: "IndexName" Missing required parameter in
>   GlobalSecondaryIndexes[5]: "KeySchema" Missing required parameter in
>   GlobalSecondaryIndexes[5]: "Projection"

This is what I have

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
--region=eu-west-2 \
--endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 \
--table-name PBA2 \
--attribute-definitions \
    AttributeName=PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI1PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI1SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI2PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI2SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI3PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI3SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI4PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI4SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI5PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI5SK,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema \
    AttributeName=PK,KeyType=HASH \
    AttributeName=SK,KeyType=RANGE \
--provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10 \
--global-secondary-indexes \
'IndexName=GSI1,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=GSI1PK,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=GSI1SK,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}' \
'IndexName=GSI2,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=GSI2PK,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=GSI2SK,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}' \
'IndexName=GSI3,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=GSI3PK,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=GSI3SK,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}' \
'IndexName=GSI4,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=GSI4PK,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=GSI4SK,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}' \
'IndexName=GSI5,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=GSI5PK,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=GSI5SK,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}' \
ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10}"
```

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402300/aws-cli-dynamodb-create-table-with-multiple-secondary-index) but as you see, I am not getting the result I want. How can I add multiple GSIs?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you really should put this in a CloudFormation template. Here is a complete example: https://github.com/dokklib/dokklib-db/blob/master/tests/integration/cloudformation.yml

Comment: I am learning to use dynamoDB locally. I will have to learn Cloudformation at some point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have accidentally supplied `ProvisionedThroughput=...` as a 6th GSI.

Instead, it should be an (optional) attribute on each of the first 5 GSIs. Something like this (quote as needed:

```
IndexName=GSI1,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=GSI1PK,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=GSI1SK,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL},ProvisionedThroughput={ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10} \
IndexName=GSI2,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=GSI2PK,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=GSI2SK,KeyType=RANGE}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL},ProvisionedThroughput={ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10} \
....
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that; however, after fixing it, it still doesn't work. It hangs... no error shown :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
--region=eu-west-2 \
--endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 \
--table-name PBA2 \
--attribute-definitions \
    AttributeName=PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI1PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI1SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI2PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI2SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI3PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI3SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI4PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI4SK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI5PK,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=GSI5SK,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema \
    AttributeName=PK,KeyType=HASH \
    AttributeName=SK,KeyType=RANGE \
--provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10 \
--global-secondary-indexes \
IndexName=GSI1,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=GSI1PK,KeyType=HASH}","{AttributeName=GSI1SK,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=ALL}",ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10}" \
IndexName=GSI2,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=GSI2PK,KeyType=HASH}","{AttributeName=GSI2SK,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=ALL}",ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10}" \
IndexName=GSI3,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=GSI3PK,KeyType=HASH}","{AttributeName=GSI3SK,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=ALL}",ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10}" \
IndexName=GSI4,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=GSI4PK,KeyType=HASH}","{AttributeName=GSI4SK,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=ALL}",ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10}" \
IndexName=GSI5,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=GSI5PK,KeyType=HASH}","{AttributeName=GSI5SK,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=ALL}",ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10}"
```